# Олимпиадная задача на ДП

Tags: c++, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

Прямо неудобно, но...

Малому задали домашку - выбрать и порешать любые задачки по ДП c e-olymp. Он выбрал среди прочих [эту](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/5849) (текст ниже). Пришел ко мне через часик - что не так? Почему проходит только 22%?

Задача выглядит простейше, но чего-то я явно не вижу, потому что никаких ошибок (ну, кроме неоптимальности) в его коде, как по мне, нет. Ткните нас - что мы в упор не видим?...

Условие:

Во многих старых играх с двумерной графикой можно столкнуться с подобной ситуацией. Какой нибуть герой прыгает по платформам (или островкам), которые висят в воздухе. Он должен перебраться с одного края экрана до другого. При этом, при прыжке с одной платформы на соседнюю, у героя уходит |y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>|<sup>2</sup> энергии, где y<sub>2</sub> и y<sub>1</sub> - высоты, на которых расположены эти платформы. Кроме того у героя есть суперприём, который позволяет перескочить через платформу, но на это затрачивается 3·|y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>|<sup>2</sup> единиц энергии. Конечно же, энергию следует расходовать максимально экономно.

Предположим, что вам известны координаты всех платформ в порядке от левого края до правого. Сможете ли вы найти, какое минимальное количество энергии потребуется герою, чтобы добраться с первой платформы до последней?

*Входные данные*

В первой строке записано количество платформ n (2 ≤ n ≤ 100000). Вторая строка содержит n натуральных чисел, не превосходящих 4000 - высоты, на которых располагаются платформы.

*Выходные данные*

Выведите единственное число - минимальное количество энергии, которое должен потратить игрок на преодоление платформ.

Вот его решение:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long int m[100001];
long long int h[100001];

long long int sq(long long int n) { return n*n; }

long long int min(long long int x, long long int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> h[i];
    }
    m[1] = 0;
    m[2] = sq(h[2]-h[1]);

    for(int i = 3; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        m[i] = min(sq(h[i]-h[i-1]) + m[i-1],
                   3*sq(h[i]-h[i-2]) + m[i-2]);
    }
    cout << m[n] << endl;
}
```

Ну, все просто - на первой платформе энергия 0, на второй - просто квадрат (попасть можно только с первой), дальше - смотрим затраты при обычном прыжке и суперпрыжке и берем минимальные... Диапазона `long long int` за глаза хватает.

Comment: Когда я увидел заголовок и то, что автор — Вы, то у меня в голове пробежали следующие мысли: "У меня глюк...", "Ваш эккаунт взломали!", "Наверно кого-то также зовут и он имеет такую-же аватарку... Нет, это бред...". С большим облегчением я прочитал текст и увидел код. ;D

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica Ну что поделать, и такое бывает :) Тут же не просто так - перед ребенком авторитет терять не хочется :), вот и обратился "за помощью к залу". Ощущение - что я смотрю и не вижу чего-то предельно простого...

Comment: Я к сожалению в с++ не очень шарю, так что ничего особо придумать не могу...

Comment: Что не так? > ./oli
4 
1 
2 
3 
30 => 
731

Comment: @AlexGlebe  При отправке на проверку по указанному в тексте URL проходит только 22% тестов.

Comment: Вы практически каждый раз   рассматриваете минимальное значение  из затраченных энергий. Таким образом выбираете прыгать на следующую или перескочить? Но может быть расклад, что прыгнув  на следующую, потом  на третью, вы потратите больше энергии, но зато потом вы сможете менять тактику прыжков так, что будет потрачена меньше энергии в общем количестве.

Comment: Может-быть надо действительно с двух сторон навстречу всё считать? Хотя вряд-ли.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А в чем сейчас не так? Пусть с третьей есть какой-то путь круче - но тогда он будет еще круче, если я выберу путь до третьей с минимальной энергией, нет?

Comment: если в вашем решении просто отсортировать высоты, то проходит вообще 11%, так что там похоже высоты не всё время возрастают, но также могут уменьшаться. А значит в вашем решении вы можете спрыгнуть вниз, посчитав это более оптимальным по энергии, вместо того, чтобы перепрыгнуть эту платформу и попасть на более высокую

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon А в этом что-то есть... надо подумать. как вы предлагаете обрабатывать этот вариант? Ведь потом может оказаться, что лестница пойдет вниз?

Comment: @Harry, например для высот 10,  4, -7,  5,  8,  4, -19, 3  минимальная энергия потратится в пути 1->2->4->6->8 , а по вашему коду получится 1->3->5->6(или 7 )->8

Comment: @ARHovsepyan в условии указано, что высоты это натуральные числа. Ваш пример некорректный.

Comment: @becouse, верно, я забыл, можно  минусы убрать, все равно получается тот же результат

Comment: По приведенному алгоритму массив m=[0, 36, 27, 31, 30, 34, 151, 37]  1-3-5-6-8. По вашему варианту будет 45

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Дело в том, что квадратичная функция "быстро" растет, поэтому
герой иногда будет двигаться назад.

Пример

```
11 2 10 1
11-2-1=81+3=84
11-10-1 = 3+81 =84
11-10-2-1 = 3+64+3 =70
```

Пусть m[i] это минимум энергии 1->i.

Поставим m[1] = 0.

Если n=2,  то на вторую мы можем попасть одним способом.

Если n>2, то двумя 1-2 или 1-3-2.

Теперь рассмотрим вычисление m[i].

Доступ к i-платформе можно получить с помощью (i - 1) или с помощью (i - 2), 
суперпeрудар.

Если i < n, то можно попасть на i-платформу с (i + 1), на которую вы перескочили с (i - 1).

m[i]=min из

- m[i - 1] + |yi - yi-1|^2 : обычный переход с (i - 1) платформы;
- m[i - 2] + 3 * |yi - yi-2|^2 : Суперудар с (i - 2) платформы;
- m[i - 1] + 3 * |yi+1 - yi-1|^2 + |yi - yi+1|^2 : 1-3-2

Пример кода

```
#define MAX 100005

...
m[1] = 0;

if (n == 2)

  m[2] = sq(h[2] - h[1]);

else

  m[2] = min(sq(h[1] - h[2]), 3 * sq(h[1] - h[3]) + sq(h[2] - h[3]));


for(int i = 3; i <= n; i++)

{

  m[i] = min(m[i - 1] + sq(h[i - 1] - h[i]), 
                m[i - 2] + 3 * sq(h[i - 2] - h[i]));

  if (i < n)
     m[i] = min(m[i], m[i - 1] + 3 * sq(h[i - 1] - h[i + 1]) + sq(h[i] - h[i + 1]));

}

 cout <<  m[n];
```