# Динамическое программирование на JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, разработка-игр

для игры необходимо реализовать алгоритм на js: 
Игрок находятся на нулевой платформе. Ему нужно дойти до платформы N. Игрок может прыгать или на следующую платформу, или через одну. Если игрок прыгает на соседнюю платформу он тратит |y2 - y1| энергии,  а если через одну то 3 * |y3 - y1|, где yn - высота n-платформы. Нужно найти минимальное количество энергии, чтобы игрок добрался до платформы N.

Я начал пытаться писать данный алгоритм, но застрял в тупике.

```js
var maxPlatforms = round(10);
var remainder = maxPlatforms % 2;
var energy = 3 * ((maxPlatforms - remainder) / 2);

if(remainder > 0) {
    energy = energy + 2;
};

return energy
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Олимпиадная задача на ДП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093953/%d0%9e%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%94%d0%9f)

Comment: Нормально так дубликат попался xD

Comment: @AlexKrass, я видел данный вопрос и он не является дубликатом, т.к. там абсолютно другие входные данные и условия немного другие.

Comment: Как скажете, я отзову тогда голос на закрытие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните с конца. Попасть на n-ю платформу можно с предпоследней или с предпредпоследней, так что

```
F(N) = Min(F(N-1) + abs(y(n)-y(n-1)),  F(N-2) + 3*abs(y(n)-y(n-2)))
```

Рекурсивно решайте до нулевой платформы. Когда всё заработает, можно преобразовать в динамическое программирование (мемоизация), запоминая лучшие варианты для каждой платформы.

Answer (score 0):

```
ЗатраченоЭнергии = 0
Пока текущаяПлатформа < N цикл
  // Определить какой из вариантов менее затратен по энергии
  Если ПрыжокНаСледующую() < ПрыжокЧерезОдну() Тогда
     ЗатраченоЭнергии += ПрыжокНаСледующую()
     текущаяПлатформа += 1
  Иначе
     ЗатраченоЭнергии += ПрыжокЧерезОдну()
     текущаяПлатформа += 2
  КонецЕсли
КонецЦикла
```

Comment: Что в данном псевдокоде является ПрыжокНаСледующую() и ПрыжокЧерезОдну()?